# Build an array of JSON objects from a spreadsheet table

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a reference for how to create an array from a table using Google app script.
not sure how I'm looping through a 3 rows table with 3 columns and save the data into [] var.

like:

```
   var users = [
   {
       firstname: '', lastname: '', phone: ''
     },
     {
       firstname: '', lastname: '', phone: ''
     }
   ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### From spreadsheet to 2D array of json objects:

**Explanation:**

I found this very useful code snippet on [github](https://gist.github.com/sarfarazansari/7e8ae05168b80b36016eb1c561a82f73) which you can use to achieve your goal.

- It assumes that the first row of the data is the headers.

**Code snippet:**

```
function myFunction() {

 // get the data from the sheet
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // change to the name of your sheet
 const arr = sh.getRange('A1:C'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
 
 //create JSON object from 2 dimensional Array

    //assuming header
    var keys = arr[0];
    //vacate keys from main array
    var newArr = arr.slice(1, arr.length);

    var formatted = [],
    data = newArr,
    cols = keys,
    l = cols.length;
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            var d = data[i],
                    o = {};
            for (var j=0; j<l; j++)
                    o[cols[j]] = d[j];
            formatted.push(o);
    }
 
 // formatted is the desired result
 console.log(formatted) // 2D array of json objects
    
}
```

**Output (`formatted`) based on data of the sheet used in the next section:**

[image: example1]

### From 2D array of json objects to spreadsheet:

**Explanation:**

You can iterate over the [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) of the object elements of the `users` array.

- The following script will create a 2D array of the raw data so it can be directly pasted in the desired sheet using the [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) and [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) method.

**Code snippet:**

```
function myFunction() {

 // the raw data
 const users = [
   {
       firstname: 'George', lastname: 'Brown', phone: '12345'
     },
     {
       firstname: 'Nick', lastname: 'Yellow', phone: '67890'
     }
   ];
 
 // get headers and rows from users
 const data = [Object.keys(users[0])]
 users.forEach(js=>{
  data.push(Object.values(js));
 });
   
 // paste data back to the sheet
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // change to the name of your sheet
 sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
    
}
```

**Example sheet used for the code snippet:**

[image: example2]

Comment: wow perfect. I will have to modify the lastrow() function but it's doing the job!

Comment: BTW - why getRange('H29').setValue([formatted]); will not print the array in the cell?

Comment: `formatted` is a 2d array and `[formatted]` is an 1D array. But setValue accepts a single element, not arrays. You can convert the full array to a string : `getRange('H29').setValue([formatted].toString())`. I can't test it right now but it should work. Try also `formatted.toString()`. If you want to get a single element then you need something like `formatted[1][0]` which will give you the element in the second row and first column

Comment: in both cases im getting [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],......